# EditText giving error : TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled

Tags: android

I have `RecyclerView`.The element at position is 0 is header for `EditText` ,then all other elements are images.On long pressing on `EditText` it gives option paste.This works fine.
But when I scroll the recycler view to the bottom and again come to top and long press it will not show the paste option and gives error .
On Scrolling to the bottom and again coming to top passes call to `onBindViewHolder`.

`TextView`: `TextView` does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.

```
public class Someclass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {


    private static final int TYPE_EDIT = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    List<String> msomelist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void someMethod(List<String> somelist) {

        msomelist.clear();
        msomelist.addAll(somelist);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }




    public Someclass(Activity activity, List<String> somelist) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.msomelist.clear();
        this.msomelist.addAll(somelist);
        mContext = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (position == 0)
            return TYPE_EDIT;

        return TYPE_IMAGE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int postition = (int) view.getTag();
        msomelist.remove(postition);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       ImageView img;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_IMAGE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(somelayout, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(someotherlayout, false);


            return new OtherHolder(view);
        }
    }

    class OtherHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText editText;

        public OtherHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ediItext);
            editText.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
            some function.....
        } else if (holder instanceof OtherHolder) {
            some function
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please !

Comment: ineed your adapter and row's layout code and headers too. To determine error

Comment: done..i can find various issue lodged for same but no solution.

Answer (score 23):

This is [a known bug in the Android platform](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208169).  I didn't believe it at first, but the code @user2246055 posted is an effective workaround!

I preferred to add this in my Adapter instead of subclassing TextView:

```
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

            // Bug workaround for losing text selection ability, see:
            // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208169
            holder.textView.setEnabled(false);
            holder.textView.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I was experiencing the same problem and your solution helped me. (on Android 7.1 by the way)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it a bit? Where do you add it? What class are you overriding? And how do you use that class in the code?

Comment: It works ... I read the answer here but they gave you the credit : 

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095917

Answer (score 5):

Using following `MyEditText.java` can resolve your problem:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
private boolean mEnabled; // is this edittext enabled

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    try {
        if (!mEnabled) return;
        super.setEnabled(false);
        super.setEnabled(mEnabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.mEnabled = enabled;
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
}}
```

Comment: Actually, it took me 3 hours to try this because it didn't look as if it was related to the problem AT ALL.  But it does work!

Comment: Long click on EditText will call Editor.performLongClick() to show selection popup window.

Answer (score 4):

Long click on `EditText` will call `Editor.performLongClick()` to show selection popup window.

Before `getInsertionController().show();`

it will check `mInsertionControllerEnabled`,when you use `setText()`,TextView will call `Editor.prepareCursorControllers()` to reset `mInsertionControllerEnabled` like this:

```
boolean windowSupportsHandles = false;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mTextView.getRootView().getLayoutParams();
if (params instanceof WindowManager.LayoutParams) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) params;
    windowSupportsHandles = windowParams.type < WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_SUB_WINDOW
            || windowParams.type > WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAST_SUB_WINDOW;
}

boolean enabled = windowSupportsHandles && mTextView.getLayout() != null;
mInsertionControllerEnabled = enabled && isCursorVisible();
```

as you see,`rootView` must be window type or `mInsertionControllerEnabled` will be `false`.

But when you `setText`() at `onBindViewHolder`(), the `EditText` is not `attachToWindow` yet,so we should `setEnable`() after `EditText` attachToWindow to force Editor reset `mInsertionControllerEnabled` value.Then selection will work now.

Comment: Where `mInsertionControllerEnabled` and `isCursorVisible()` come from?