# Android TextView not selectable in CoordinatorLayout? (TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

This is the error I get: `W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.`

I am stunned, because other `Textviews` I have implemented before in a `RelativeLayout` have had text selectable when I have the property `android:textIsSelectable="true"` - however, doesn't work this time.

This code is placed under `app_bar_main.xml` using an `include` keyword in XML.

Here is `app_bar_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" /> //This is where the textview is added!

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the edited `content_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.androidterminal.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    //I have some other LinearLayouts here
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This TextView `main1` is not selectable and throws the aforementioned warning on LogCat. Please help. Thanks. (I have already tried setting focusable and setFocusable properties)

Comment: can you plz provide @style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay, @style/ToolbarTitle.??? beause i have tried your code ..i don't have your styles, so i have removed that from xml, and it is working...it selects text ...i can show you screenshot..

Comment: Are you facing this problem in specific Android version or phones? Try using android:focusable="true" in your text view.

Comment: Also try using android:enabled = "true"

Comment: are you using ScrollView ??

Comment: I have tried focusable etc as in other answers. But it doesn't seem to work. It's in all versions. No, not using scrollview, but the textview is scrollable, yes.

Comment: Are you using this textview inside a popupwindow?? This could be the problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62508

Comment: your code works fine  for my phone.provide detail of ur emulator/phone @Zac

Comment: Have you checked out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566303/

Comment: What device are you testing on? What version of supportt libs do you use?

Answer (score 7):

Your code works fine, I am not sure what config you have on your system.

Try the following fix

1. Try this in java.

   ```
   textview.setTextIsSelectable(true);
   textview.setFocusable(true);
   textview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   ```
2. Change `TextView` width to `wrap_content` from `match_parent`.

Answer (score 2):

Using following CopyTextView.java can resolve your problem:

```
public class CopyTextView extends EditText {

private boolean mEnabled; // is this edittext enabled

public CopyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CopyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CopyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    try {
        if (!mEnabled) return;
        super.setEnabled(false);
        super.setEnabled(mEnabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.mEnabled = enabled;
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
}}
```

and then use it in your layout file

```
 <com.your_package_name.CopyTextView
        android:id="@+id/main1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this,It works , i have removed your styles which you have given in your xml

[image]

Comment: No, removing those styles didn't work for me. Still the same error, " W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled."

Comment: I also tested your code and it work just fine in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

logically thinking, the text can be selected by long click.... so textview has to be longclickable

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: Logically thinking the view would be made long clickable automatically when you requested it be selectable.