# Scrollable TextView doesn't allow to select text after the application is paused

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a scrollable `TextView` where a user can select text. I add scroll bar by setting movement method to `ScrollingMovementMethod`.

**Problem:** Selection works well unless the application is paused (for instance, after switching apps). Once the app is active again selection stops working and I get the following message in log:

> W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Selection
>   cancelled.

**My setup:**

I have an Activity with `CoordinatorLayout` and a Fragment with a `TextView` wrapped into `RelativeLayout` which looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

And in Java code I have to do:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

because this was the only working way according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15857755/2065796), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37566303/2065796) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095917) issues.

**EDIT:**

The problem is in the following call

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

If I remove it it works, but I can't get why.

**Minimal steps to reproduce the issue:**

1) Create an empty Activity with a `TextView` using the following layout.

```js
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:text="Some very very very long text..."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2) Set up visibility parameters of the `TextView` in `onStart()` method.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        textView.setFocusable(true);
        textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
}
```

3) Try to use context menu on the `TextView` before and after pausing the application.

**EDIT 2:**

Removing `setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` solves my problem and the functionality works well after that. But I'm not quite sure why it was added and I'm afraid it will brake something if I remove it. Any idea why one might use `ScrollingMovementMethod` in combination with `android:scrollbars="vertical"`. May be xml doesn't work in some cases? Ideas? And I'm still interested why using `ScrollingMovementMethod` brakes selection functionality?

Comment: Where are you putting that Java code? Try putting it under `onResume()`. Also, why not try using the `android:textIsSelectable` XML attribute?

Comment: @TheWanderer My code is in ´onCreate()´ right now and it is there only because if I add it to xml it simply doesn’t work (please check the links I added, it is wired, but it is reality).  I’ll try putting it to ‘onResume()‘ a bit later (not near my laptop right now)

Comment: @TheWanderer doing it in `onResume()` unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? I can not reproduce such an issue: selection is working just fine with `android:textIsSelectable="true"` attribute.

Comment: @ozbek please find the edit with the detailed test case.

Comment: Putting the same block of code inside onCreate works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting `ScrollingMovementMethod` gives `TextView` ability to scroll "by own", e.g. when you set really long text and it is cutted on bottom or edge. with `ScrollingMovementMethod` you can scroll `TextView`, there is no need to place it in scrollable container, e.g. in `ScrollView` or `HorizontalScrollView`

`android:scrollbars="vertical"` line says that IF this `View` get "scrollablility" (e.g. by above movement method) then UI should show only `vertical` scrollbar. from docs:

> Defines which scrollbars should be displayed on scrolling or not.

and it is [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) docs, not `TextView` especially, because few extending "kinds" of `View`s can gain "scolllability", including all `ViewGroup`s like `ScrollView`, `ListView`, `RecyclerView` etc.

and finally what this line is doing in your code? inside [`setTextIsSelectable`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) you have this line:

```
setMovementMethod(selectable ? ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance() : null);
```

so in fact its overwritting movement method you set few lines above in your own code. I bet that some time ago your `TextView` was scollable "by itself" and some day some smart guy rewritten this and put `TextView` in e.g. `ScrollView` in XML, and movement method stayed in code.

`textIsSelectable` is working until `Activity` pause, because after resuming you are (again) setting `ScrollableMovementMethod`, but inside `setTextIsSelectable` you have

```
 if (mEditor.mTextIsSelectable == selectable) return;
```

you set that `mTextIsSelectable` flag in first run before `Activity`s pause, and this flag is restored, so code below isn't fired (so movement method isn't re-set with `ArrowKeyMovementMethod` and your `ScrollableMovementMethod` stays). So answer for question what this line is doing in your code: it's breaking "selectionability" after pausing and resuming `Activity`, nothing besides that

note from sources of [`ScrollingMovementMethod`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/18728e9dd5dd66d4f5edf1b792e77e2b544a1cb0/sdk/sources/android-19/android/text/method/ScrollingMovementMethod.java) and [`ArrowKeyMovementMethod`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/method/ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java): only in `ArrowKeyMovementMethod` (set as movement method inside `setTextIsSelectable` like above) you have overriden `onTouchEvent` method and inside it some lines handling selection

edit: note also that inside `setTextIsSelectable` you have setting "focusability", so these lines are unnecessary:

```
textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

so you can shorten your code to just one line:

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

or remove all quoted Java code and add one XML line:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I don't have a `ScrollView`, in my case there is only a `RelativeLayout`. But now I'm wandering if it works even without `textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` call why it is recommended for instance in this highly rated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/2065796 ?  Basically `android:scrollbars="vertical"` does the job without any java code.

Comment: `android:scrollbars="vertical"` just shows `vertical` scrollbars when content (text) is larger than `View`. it doesn't/should't make `TextView` scrollable "by own" e.g. on touch/swipe. create some dummy `TextView`, set fixed width (e.g. 100dp), height (40dp) and really long text. without `maxLines`, `singleLine`, `ellipsize` and other "shortening" methods text won't fit and will be cutted on bottom. with `android:scrollbars="vertical"` `TextView` will show vertical scrollbar indicating that it have more content, but without `ScrollingMovementMethod` it won't be scrollable by touch

Comment: I my case it is somehow scrollable even without this call.

Comment: check if it is scrollable without `setTextIsSelectable(true);` (or even with forced `setMovementMethod(null)` on the end) - `ArrowKeyMovementMethod` has also calling `Touch.onTouchEvent(...)` like `ScrollableMovementMethod` does in `onTouch`, so there is a chance that it can also handle scroll gesture

Comment: You are correct, scrolling stops working of I remove `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

Answer (score 4):

Please replace below code from your XML.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Remove below code from program:

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

The internal code of **setTextIsSelectable()** method:

```
public void setTextIsSelectable(boolean selectable) {
        if (!selectable && mEditor == null) return; // false is default value with no edit data

        createEditorIfNeeded();
        if (mEditor.mTextIsSelectable == selectable) return;

        mEditor.mTextIsSelectable = selectable;
        setFocusableInTouchMode(selectable);
        setFocusable(FOCUSABLE_AUTO);
        setClickable(selectable);
        setLongClickable(selectable);

        // mInputType should already be EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL and mInput should be null

        setMovementMethod(selectable ? ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance() : null);
        setText(mText, selectable ? BufferType.SPANNABLE : BufferType.NORMAL);

        // Called by setText above, but safer in case of future code changes
        mEditor.prepareCursorControllers();
    }
```

Programmatically they are also doing the same thing which I mentioned in XML. So depending on your requirements we can use it.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this didn't work, I tried it already. As I mentioned **I only set the parameters in java code because this was the only working way** (at least partly working). With the code you added I get `W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.` in logs. I'll try to narrower the problem add add more details.

Comment: Please find the edit with some new findings and the detailed test case on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota: Please have a look at updated answer

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want me to try. As I mentioned xml way didn't work and eventually I identified that the problem was in setting `ScrollingMovementMethod`. Did you read the edits?

Answer (score 3):

I had very similar problem; texview could scroll but not selectable.

Remove this from your code:

`texview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())`

I add these to your textview in xml:

`android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Comment: odd that it says scrollHorizontally but with `android:scrollbars="vertical"` it still scrolls vertical lol. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make TextView selectable in two ways

through XML:

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

through Java code:

```
 textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: As you might see **it is already present in my code** and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please find the edit with some new findings and the detailed test case on how to reproduce the problem.