# The property textIsSelectable does not work on the TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, properties, textview

I would like to have a TextView such that the user can select/copy the text from the TextView. The TextView is part of a Fragment in a TabLayout. The Fragment has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_translator_text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_default"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_textsize_translator"
        android:padding="@dimen/edittext_padding_translator"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_height_spacing" />

    <EditText
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/edittext_translator_text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_default"
        android:hint="@string/type_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_textsize_translator"
        android:padding="@dimen/edittext_padding_translator"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the corresponding Java code is as follows:

```
public class FragmentText extends Fragment {

    private TextView textView;

    private View rootView;

    private TextTranslator textTranslator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);

        textTranslator = new TextTranslator();

        initializeTextView();
        initializeEditText();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initializeTextView() {
        textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_translator_text);

        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }

    private void initializeEditText() {
        EditText editText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_translator_text);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                // currently not used
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String textInBinary = textTranslator.getBinarySequence(charSequence.toString());

                textView.setText(textInBinary);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                // currently not used
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I expected that the text of the TextView is selectable (since I am using the property textIsSelectable). However, for some reason, the text is **not** selectable.

I've tested the application on multiple devices with different Android versions, and on none of these devices the text was selectable.

Any suggestion how I *can* make the text of the TextView selectable?

Comment: Thats strange indeed, as setting ```android:textIsSelectable="true"```  should work. Are you setting some listeners on the textview in your java class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow reached back at this post. Looking at the edit you made to your question the cause of your issue seems to be this line

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

inside your `initializeTextView()` method.

In simple terms its overwriting what you set in the xml with `android:textIsSelectable="true"` You can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768816/scrollable-textview-doesnt-allow-to-select-text-after-the-application-is-paused) for some more info of how it's causing the issue.

Simplest solution is to remove the scrolling movement method from code and use `android:textIsSelectable="true"` in xml or set `TextView` as selectable programatically

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

as it seems to set values of some other properties like focusable, focusableInTouchMode, longClickable to true too.

Comment: Removing the line `textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` did the trick!